# How to exclude files from publish after precompile?

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, publish

I would like to publish my web application with precompilation. I have some parts of the configuration externalized in a Config folder (using configSource attribute in the web.config). Obviously, those files are required when I publish with precompilation. However, they are specific to one environment. As I would like to be able to deploy to multiple environments which may already have these config files. I would like to remove the config folder from the publish folder.

I tried a wpp.targets as the following :

```
<ExcludeFromPackageFolders Include="Config" />
```

However, this happens before the precompilation, and is therefore too early.

Any idea ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: would not including  webconfig for all environments using transformation serve your purposes?

Comment: Actually, I can't since I don't know how is configured every environment. These config files contains smtp strings and connections strings which, are specific to our customers.